# Failed deploying application using Worklight Console: "Failed to deploy application <appName>.wlapp'. : ERROR

Tags: websphere-7, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using Worklight 5.0.6.20130311-0918, running on WebSphere application server (7.0.0.21) on RedHat Linux, and I'm trying to deploy an app using Worklight Console. I'm getting an error:

> 'Failed to deploy application
>   'CitizenCollaboration-android-1.0.5.wlapp'. : ERROR'

There is not much information in WebSphere's SystemOut.log. I tried increasing the trace level in the App Server Admin Console but still not enough error information.

Note: I'm able to deploy worklight adapters successfully

### Authentication.xml

```
<staticResources>
    <resource id="worklightConsole" securityTest="WorklightConsole">
        <urlPatterns>/console*</urlPatterns>
    </resource>
</staticResources>


<securityTests>

   <customSecurityTest name="WorklightConsole">
     <test realm="WorklightConsole" isInternalUserID="true"/>
   </customSecurityTest>

    <mobileSecurityTest name="WAS-mobileSecurityTest">
        <testDeviceId provisioningType="none" />
        <!-- <testUser realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm"/>  -->
        <testUser realm="WASLTPARealm"/>
    </mobileSecurityTest>

    <webSecurityTest name="WAS-webSecurityTest">
        <testUser realm="WASLTPARealm"/> 
    </webSecurityTest>

    <customSecurityTest name="pushSecurityTest">
        <test realm="PushBackendRealm" isInternalUserID="true"/>
    </customSecurityTest>

</securityTests>

<realms>
    <realm loginModule="StrongDummy" name="SampleAppRealm">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
    </realm>
    <realm loginModule="requireLogin" name="WorklightConsole">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
        <onLoginUrl>/console</onLoginUrl>
    </realm>
    <realm loginModule="requireLogin" name="PushBackendRealm">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.BasicAuthenticator</className>
        <parameter name="basic-realm-name" value="CitizenCollaboration" />
    </realm>
     <realm name="WASLTPARealm" loginModule="WASLTPAModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereFormBasedAuthenticator</className>
        <parameter name="login-page" value="/login.html"/>
        <parameter name="error-page" value="/loginError.html"/>
    </realm>
</realms>

<loginModules>
    <loginModule name="StrongDummy">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>
    <loginModule name="requireLogin">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>
    <loginModule name="WASLTPAModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>
</loginModules>
```

Comment: Find Worklight's server.log in your WAS installation, see if there is any information there. Add some information about your app/project. Is it a blank app? are you doing anything special there? Have you changed worklight.properties or authenticationConfig.xml? If yes, you must redeploy the .war file to WAS. Edit the question with this information.

Comment: That's the strange part, I don't find server.log in linux environment. If I turn on trace level in WebSphere for worklight class, the information goes to trace.log. And I don't see anything there, except the worklight core class file is working and phase3 and rollsback. Yes, I redeployed the war file and I still don't get much error information during deployment.

Comment: Edit the question with the little information written to SystemOut.log, please also move worklight.properties from the comment above, to the question... finally, add your application-descriptor.xml as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Some experiments to do:**

1. Make sure that you are using the same Worklight version in both WAS
   (the Worklight Server you have installed on it) and Worklight Studio
   (the Eclipse plug-in you use in order to, eventually, generate the .wlapp).

   To find out the Worklight version you have installed in WAS,
   load Worklight Console and click on the "About" link at the top-right corner. The version number is displayed there.

   To find out the Worklight version you have installed in
   Eclipse, go to the Help menu >> About >> click the Worklight icon.
   The version number is displayed there.

   Mismatched Worklight versions are not recommended to have, and will can/will cause such errors.
2. Remove the securityTests you have placed in the various environment elements in  `application-descriptor.xml` and generate a new .wlapp; try deploying it and see if deployment now passes.

   Alternatively, also make sure that if you have securityTests set in application-descriptor.xml, they are written correclty (match those defined in authenticationConfig.xml).

   This can indicate on a possible problem in `authenticationConfig.xml`.

Comment: Good Catch Idan. Version was the problem. I was using 5.0.3 Studio against 5.0.6 server. I upgraded my studio to 5.0.6 and everything works. Thanks a lot