# IBM Worklight 5.0.6 defined in loginmodule 'rejectAll' in the authentication configuration file doesn't exist

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I created the new Worklight project and application in Worklight v5.0.6 and it's running fine in the Developer Edition.

After building the project and trying to deploy it to my application server I get this error message:

```
nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Class 'com.worklight.core.auth.ext.RejectingLoginModule' defined in login module 'rejectAll' in the authentication configuration file doesn't exist."
```

Comment: Before dumping a huge log, please describe what exactly have you done... did you create a new project? is this a sample project? did you create it with a studio version that differs from the server version in Liberty? Some background about what you're doing...

Comment: Please edit the question with the information... not in comments.

Comment: and? what did you do next to get the error? Please edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer here: [Failed deploying application using Worklight Console: "Failed to deploy application <appName>.wlapp'. : ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601719/failed-deploying-application-using-worklight-console-failed-to-deploy-applicat)

1. Make sure that you are using the same Worklight version in both WAS
   (the Worklight Server you have installed on it) and Worklight Studio
   (the Eclipse plug-in you use in order to, eventually, generate the .wlapp).

   To find out the Worklight version you have installed in WAS,
   load Worklight Console and click on the "About" link at the top-right corner. The version number is displayed there.

   To find out the Worklight version you have installed in
   Eclipse, go to the Help menu >> About >> click the Worklight icon.
   The version number is displayed there.

   Mismatched Worklight versions are not recommended to have, and can/will cause such errors.